# arrayfire SVD jobu and jobvt parameters

Tags: svd, arrayfire

The `svd` and `svdInPlace` functions provided by Arrayfire are hard-wired to use `'A'` as the parameter for `jobu` and `jobvt`. Is there a way to use `'S'` for this parameter instead? I need to compute the SVD of an extremely tall but narrow matrix, and I only care about a handful of the singular vectors/values.

I know that the `'S'` parameter was previously unsupported by `cusolverDnDgesvd`, but that no longer seems to be the case in CUDA 8.0.

I'm currently trying to use `cusolverDnDgesvd` directly, but running into problems when I try to use Arrayfire's device pointers (which may lead to a separate question).